# Alternative notation to *(ptr)[j++]?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When passing a double pointer to a function, I used the notation `*ptr[j++]` in my function which lead the program to crash. I guessed it happened due to operator precedence, so I rectified it by writing `(*ptr)[j++]` but I didn't like this notation. It feels long and confusing.

I also know of the notation `ptr[0][j++]` but I also don't like it.Is there any better notation or approach around all of this?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mset(int **ptr, size_t size);

void main(void)
{
    const size_t size = 10;
    int *ptr = new int[size];
    mset(&ptr, size);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < size; n++) {
        std::cout << ptr[n] << std::endl;
    }
}

void mset(int **ptr, size_t size)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while(j < size)
        (*ptr)[j++] = 3;
}
```

P.S I know that I can write `void mset(int *ptr, size_t size)` and invoke `mset(ptr, size`), but I am asking about that particular case.

Comment: What would your *ideal* notation look like, if you were designing the language?

Comment: Can't you just use `std::memset` instead?

Comment: Welcome to C++, with many parts that are "long and confusing"!

Comment: @gustafbstrom ,actually this is only a code I wrote to post on SO because I don't want to post my actual code that has this issue.

Comment: If all your usage of double pointers is as in `mset`, I'd suggest you change the function signature for `void mset(int *ptr, size_t size)`, so you can do `ptr[j++]`.

Comment: The proper alternative is to _not use double pointers_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple use an extra level of indirection, something like:

```
auto p = *ptr;
for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    p[j] = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case, inside `mset(int **ptr, size_t size)`, you are never using `ptr` as it is. but using with dereference (i.e. `*ptr`). Hence, I would recommend to **pass the pointer reference**.

```
mset(ptr, size);
//   ^^^ pass simply     

void mset(int* const &ptr, const size_t size)
{        // ^^^ pointer reference which cannot change (prevents memory leak)
    size_t j = 0;
    while(j < size)
        ptr[j++] = 3;  // No dereferencing required
}
```

You may also remove the reference as well, because you don't intend to change the value of `ptr` ever in the `mset()`. But passing as above is also fine to be able to use the same `ptr` from `main()`.

Here is the [demo](http://ideone.com/PEuPbh).
BTW, a standard compliant `main()` always returns `int`.

Comment: @layzak, will changing `ptr` (if declared as `**ptr`) be ever required in practical cases? I don't think so at least for this case. If you want to avoid `ptr` (if declared as `*&ptr`) getting changed to avoid memory leak, then you may make it a `const` pointer. See the edited code & demo.

Comment: Yes.As I mentioned in my comment,the above code is for the question.My real code with the issue entails changing the value of ptr...

Answer (score 0):

Declare the level one pointer (`int**`, and *not* `int*`) as `const`, and compiler would raise an error:

```
void mset(int const** ptr, size_t size)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while (j < size)
        *ptr[j++] = 3; // ERROR
}
```

You are sure that base pointer isn't going to change, and you don't want function to change its contents, so make is `const`. However, multiple level of pointers do cause problems, it is better to use references, 
`vectors`, templates and other better/newer alternatives.